# how to solve git error while installing linkedin from git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, linkedin-api

i get this error while using bundle install in ROR.

Fetching git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git
    fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (No such host is known. )
    Git error: command `git clone "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git" "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ca
    che/bundler/git/linkedin-3e3919d62b37a1f8879ade6b51b3eeb032fc8973" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory C:/linkedin/linke
    dinfrongit has failed.

I am using windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you behind a firewall blocking connections on port 9418? Perhaps you can give it a try with the http protocol?

```
git clone https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set proxy using git config command in the command prompt with
the following two commands: 
    git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@host:port 
    git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@host:port

In command like:
    git clone git://github.com/saasbook/hw2_rottenpotatoes.git
Replace replace git:// with https://.
    git clone https://github.com/saasbook/hw2_rottenpotatoes.git
```